# Meteor helper not called when Session changes

Tags: meteor

The following calls messages when the page loads but not when a Session value is changed. Here is the template code;

```
<head>
  <title>Your welcome to chat</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> chat}}
</body>

<template name="chat">
    <div class="ui list" style='height: 100px; overflow:scroll;' id='chatHistory'>
        {{> currentChatList}}
    </div>
    <div class="ui large icon input">
        <input type="text" class="field" id="message" placeholder="Type your message here" />
        <i class="comment icon"></i>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="currentChatList">
    {{#each messages}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Here is the code;

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.chat.events ({
        'keydown input#message' : function (event) {
            if (event.which == 13) { // 13 is the enter key event
                Session.set('time', new Date());
            }
        }
    });
    Template.currentChatList.helpers({
        messages : function () {
            debugger;
            return [];
        }
    });
}
```

debugger statement is hit when the page loads, but not when the enter key is pressed on the textbox and Session.set('time'..) is executed. I thought a Session value change would cause the template to render.

Comment: Your event map setup was broken, `Template.myTemplate.events` is a function that takes the event map as argument, not a property you should assign to the event map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not depend on the `Session` variable you're assigning anywhere on your code. A reactive computation such as template helpers only reruns if one of its dependent reactive data sources is modified, which is clearly not the case in your example.

Try to depend on the `Session` variable inside your helper code to make it re-execute whenever you press enter.

```
Template.currentChatList.helpers({
  messages: function () {
    debugger;
    var time = Session.get("time");
    console.log("You pressed enter at",time);
    return [];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[saimeunt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114569/1523072) will solve you problem. Your helper at the moment doesn't access any reactive variable (Session or Collection), which means it's never executed again.

Recently more and more people prefer to use [reactive-var](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var):

- The idea is that you declare a reactive variable within your JS file and then USE that reactive variable in your helper. Every time you change the variable, all helpers using this variable are re-executed.

Comment: +1 for advocating reactive-var. However at the moment there's no de-facto standard for a Meteor component system so it can be difficult (definitely doable but using an over-complicated syntax) to share a reactive-var between a parent template and a child template, which seems to be the point in OP question.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Cross-template is a bit more difficult. However I think when you keep the helper and the event in the same file, you might get away with a local variable inside that JS file.

Comment: Well, if you make the reactive-var a file-scoped global this is easy, but it makes more sense to attach the reactive-var as a property of the template instance to make your template a somehow reusable component.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY THE ANSWER: OMG.

https://blog.meteor.com/the-meteor-chef-reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables-971584515a27

I have tried window.someVariableThatChanges = NOT WORKING

I have tried a Session.someVariableThatChanges = NOT WORKING

REACTIVE VARIABLE -- TOTALLY WORKING.

The difference is that you need to create a Template ON CREATED event, add your variables there. Simply use this variable in your even that changes the value, and your helper reference -- it works like magic and feels soooooo goooooood.